# How to disable gettext feature?

Tags: localization

Just trying to entirely disable localization support of a site.

Tried removing the `gettext`-filter, using `override_load_textdomain`-filter, and looked into every possible site with no luck. Can this be disabled entirely without hacking the core?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer, but perhaps you're not running your code early enough.

Returning true from the [override_load_textdomain](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/override_load_textdomain/) filter will prevent all MO files from loading, but you'll have to run it early to catch WordPress Core translations. Adding it as a [must-use plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) does the trick for me:

```
/*
 Plugin Name: Disable Gettext
*/
add_filter('override_load_textdomain','__return_true');
```